# @CacheRemoveAll not work

Tags: java

@CacheRemoveAll not clear cache. Every time when I call getTechnologyColorObjcts(), my data will be cached. but when I call deleteTechnologyColorObjects(), cache is still there.

```
     @Singleton(name = "ThematicTechnologyColorCache")
        @Startup
        @Lock(LockType.READ)
        @CacheDefaults(cacheName = "ThematicTechnologyColorCache")
        @Keep
        @KeepName
        @KeepClassMemberNames
        public class ThematicTechnologyColorCache {

            @Inject
            private WebPortalManager webPortalManager;

            @CacheResult(cacheName = "ThematicTechnologyColorCache")
            public HashMap<String, List<ThemeText>> getTechnologyColorObjects() {
                HashMap<String, List<ThemeText>> technologyColorsList = null;
                HashMap<String, Integer> profileIDList = getProfileIDList();


                if (profileIDList.size() != 0 && profileIDList != null) {
                    technologyColorsList = getTechnologyColorList(profileIDList);

                }

                return technologyColorsList;
            }
        //This function is not working
            @CacheRemoveAll(cacheName = "ThematicTechnologyColorCache")
            public void deleteObjects() {
                logger.warning("In deleteTechnologyColorObjects");
            }
```

Comment: How do you know the cache is still there? Set up logging in `getTechnologyColorObjects` and see if the results are from the cache or if the method is executed.

Comment: I checked that earlier, method is not called